# Extruding faces through overhanging geometry, how to avoid self intersecting in object?

Tags: modeling, extrude, intersection

I want to extrude surfaces far enough that the objects faces will intersect. Is there a neat way to trim all related faces and remove the parts that are "inside" the object?

Like some sort of "self boolean" I suppose(?)

[image]

[image]

Comment: If these are 2 different meshes you can select one and Ctrl F > Intersect (Boolean) but if this is only one mesh I don't think there's any way to automatically remove inner faces

Answer (score -1):

Fixed thanks to some more searching -> https://developer.blender.org/T93308

Comment: Hi Leo, glad you've got a fix. Since these Q&A posts both need a bit more clarification to be self-contained and searchable, for the archive, .. we can just close this case? If you want to expand on them, we can re-open.

Comment: Ok, its fine.  !

Comment: Thanks very much. Nothing personal :)